# Draw & zoom using Canvas: Canvas Deleting the Previously Drawn Shape

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

here i got a code to Draw image in canvas and Zoom it. So i can draw the Shape that i have selected in the given drop down.,
My problem is If i select line and draw the line, then i select rectangle and draw the rectangle, now the previouly drawn line has been removed
from my canvas., I need all my shapes that i have drawn should be there in my canvas., I have given my complete code below (just copy and paste it
on your work space),
Please help, since i wasting my time for last 2 days

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>

 <div id="controls">
    <button id="zoomIn">Zoom In</button>
    <button id="zoomOut">Zoom Out</button>
    <button id="clear">Clear</button>
</div>

  <style type="text/css">
  #container { position: relative; }
  #imageView { border: 1px solid #000; }
  #imageTemp { position: absolute; top: 1px; left: 1px; }
</style>

 <p><label>Drawing tool: <select id="dtool">
     <option value="pencil">Pencil</option>
    <option value="line" selected>Line</option>
    <option value="rect" >Rectangle</option>
   
    <option value="arc">Full Circle</option>
    <option value="lefthalfcircle">Left Half Circle</option>
    <option value="righthalfcircle">Right Half Circle</option>
    
    <option value="Erase">Erase</option>
 </select></label></p>


 <div id="container">
  <canvas id="imageView" width="900" height="400">
    <p>Unfortunately, your browser is currently unsupported by our web
    application.  We are sorry for the inconvenience. Please use one of the
    supported browsers listed below, or draw the image you want using an
    offline tool.</p>
    <p>Supported browsers: <a href="http://www.opera.com">Opera</a>, <a
      href="http://www.mozilla.com">Firefox</a>, <a
      href="http://www.apple.com/safari">Safari</a>, and <a
      href="http://www.konqueror.org">Konqueror</a>.</p>
  </canvas>
 </div>

 
 <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[




 $(document).ready(function () {
 var canvas = document.getElementById("imageView"),
    paintContext = imageView.getContext("2d"),
    currentPathIndex = 0,
    draw = false,
    paths = [],
    scale = 1,
    scaleStep = 0.25,
    styles = {
        lineWidth: 10,
        strokeStyle: "#000000"
    };

 paintContext.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
 paintContext.mozImageSmoothingEnabled=false;
 paintContext.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled=false;
 var cvSize = 500;

 var drawCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
 var drawCtx = drawCanvas.getContext('2d');

 drawCanvas.width = drawCanvas.height = cvSize;
 canvas.width = canvas.height = cvSize;

 var context = drawCtx;

 function updatePaintCanvas() {

        paintContext.clearRect(0, 0, paintContext.canvas.width, paintContext.canvas.height); 
    paintContext.save();
    paintContext.translate(cvSize*0.5, cvSize*0.5);
    paintContext.scale(scale, scale);
    paintContext.drawImage(drawCanvas, -cvSize*0.5, -cvSize*0.5);
    
    paintContext.restore();
        
 }

 
 var canvasRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
var mouse = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
 };

 function getCoords(e) {
    mouse.x = e.clientX || e.pageX || 0;
    mouse.y = e.clientY || e.pageY || 0;
    mouse.x -= canvasRect.left;
    mouse.y -= canvasRect.top;
    mouse.x = cvSize*0.5 + (mouse.x - cvSize*0.5)/scale;
    mouse.y = cvSize*0.5 + (mouse.y - cvSize*0.5)/scale;
}

function applyStyles(context, styles) {
    for (var style in styles)
    context[style] = styles[style];
};

function reDrawHistory() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
    context.save();
    applyStyles(context, styles);
    scaleFromCenter(context, scale);
    for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(paths[i][0].x, paths[i][0].y);
        for (var j = 1; j < paths[i].length; j++)
        context.lineTo(paths[i][j].x, paths[i][j].y);
        context.stroke();
    }
    context.restore();
}

function zoom(context, paths, styles, scale) {

};

$("#clear").on("click", function () {
    paths = [];
    currentPathIndex = 0;
    context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
});

$("#zoomIn").on("click", function () {
    scale += scaleStep;
    updatePaintCanvas();
});

$("#zoomOut").on("click", function () {
    scale -= scaleStep;
    updatePaintCanvas();
});

$("#imageView").on("mousedown", function (e) {
   tool=document.getElementById("dtool").value;
    getCoords(e);
    draw = true;
    context.save();
    applyStyles(context, styles);
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
    updatePaintCanvas();
    Startx=mouse.x;
    Starty=mouse.y;
    
    // save the path to memory
    if (typeof paths[currentPathIndex] == 'undefined') paths[currentPathIndex] = [];

    paths[currentPathIndex].push({
        x: mouse.x,
        y: mouse.y
    })

});

$("#imageView").on("mousemove", function (e) {
    
    getCoords(e);
    if (draw) {
         context.lineWidth = 1;
         context.strokeStyle = "#000";
         //context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        console.log(tool)
         context.clearRect(0, 0, drawCanvas.width, drawCanvas.height);
        if(tool=='line'){ 
      context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(Startx, Starty);
  context.lineTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
  context.stroke();

  
  }else if(tool=='rect'){
            context.beginPath();

 context.rect(Startx, Starty, mouse.x, mouse.y);

 context.stroke();


 }else{
        context.lineTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
        context.stroke();
                   
      
        }
         context.save();
         updatePaintCanvas();
          paths[currentPathIndex].push({
            x: mouse.x,
            y: mouse.y
        })
        
    }
});

 $("#imageView").on("mouseup", function (e) {
    draw = false;
   // context.restore();
    currentPathIndex++;
    updatePaintCanvas();
    
 });



 });


 //]]></script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate for [line and rectangle in canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55122936) with updated answer in JSFiddle  [jsfiddle.net/5dkx72gh/6](https://jsfiddle.net/5dkx72gh/6/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [line and rectangle in canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55121326/line-and-rectangle-in-canvas)

Comment: @Kyojimaru no, i have zoom option too